# unable to reboot the Broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, reboot

I am creating an service which is use Service Component  ,I want to run the application always in background . Suppose i switch off the mobile and when i on the mobile our application is closed  i.e. automatically.

am trying this code

androidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.ConnectionReceiver">
<intent-filter> 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
</intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

and adding this code in BroadCastreceiver Class
**update**

```
private class ConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

        private Timer mTimer;
        private TimerTask mTimerTask;
        private long interval;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE); 
             PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent(context, ConnectionReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
             am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + interval, interval, pi); 
                {
                calGps();
                }
                }
```

Comment: add permission in manifest file "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />"

Comment: i already added that permission

Comment: Please post the first line of the ConnectionReceiver Class

Comment: @lucifier that is my full code.

Comment: Please come to this chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6137/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi [Leema Rose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/988905/leema-rose)

You want to launch your service/activity after the device booted. Check the below links you will understand how to use BroadcastReceiver.

[Autostart an application at bootup](http://www.androidsnippets.com/autostart-an-application-at-bootup)

[Start Service at boot](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/)

I hope it may help you.

**New Answer:**

Add `<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />` in intent-filter of receiver's manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a manifest permission entry:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

(of course you should list all other permissions that your app uses).

Then, implement BroadcastReceiver class, it should be simple and fast executable. The best approach is to set an alarm in this receiver to wake up your service (if it's not necessary to keep it running ale the time as Prahast wrote).

```
public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent(context, MyService.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + interval, interval, pi);
}}
```

Then, add a Receiver class to your manifest file:

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".receivers.BootUpReceiver"
    android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: @lucifier i tried the above coding.But my service is not started

Comment: @LeemaRose are you restarting your device? to check the output?

Comment: ya i switch my mobile and on to start